# Why row is updated wrongly in DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

I am under a situation where I have to update the rows of two column and I am not able to find the correct solution.

I have table like this:

```
table1 :

nid  listName ltitle
1     lsn1      lst1
2     lsn2      lst2
```

and now this nid is foreign key(listid) for table2

```
table2

nid listid listcol1 listcol2
1    1     "lstxt1" "lscol1" //belongs to lsn1
2    1     "lstxt2" "lscol2" //belongs to lsn1
3    1     "lstxt3" "lscol3" //belongs to lsn1
3    2     "lstxt4" "lscol4" //belongs to lsn2
```

For better understanding there are two list named lsn1 and lsn2 and first one has 2 columns listcol1 and listcol2 and listcol1 contains the data which come 
through a string which I split through "###" as delimiter something like this `"lstxt1###lstxt2###lstxt3###"` similarly for listcol2

My try to update both table in stored prcodure on data changed by user is :

```
update table1 set listName=@listName ,ltitle=@ltitle   //table 1 update and it works well
where nid=@nid  

update table2 set listId=@nid, listcol1=a.part,listcol2= b.part from     //table2 update , problem is here
dbo.splitstring(@listcol1,'###') a inner join       
dbo.splitstring(@listcol2,'###') b on a.id=b.id where table2.listid=@nid
```

problem here is :
(1) table1 is updated properly but table2 updated output is wrong (lets say i tried to update for nid=1 in table1) :

```
listcol1 listcol2
"lstxt5" "lscol5" //belongs to lsn1
"lstxt5" "lscol5" //belongs to lsn1
"lstxt5" "lscol5"
```

I mean it updates the first row to all rows. Where as expected output was :

```
listcol1 listcol2
"lstxt5" "lscol5" //belongs to lsn1
"lstxt6" "lscol6" //belongs to lsn1
"lstxt7" "lscol7"
```

(2) when user add new row it do not show the update in that row. It must show taht as well.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code (as far as I understand your logic) for sure does not make any sense: `listcol1=a.part,listcol1= b.part`

That should give you an error like this:

> Msg 264, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The column name 'listcol1' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code."

```
update table1 set listName=@listName ,ltitle=@ltitle   //table 1 update and it works well
where nid=@nid  

update table2 set listId=@nid, **listcol1=a.part,listcol1= b.part** from     //table2 update , problem is here
dbo.splitstring(@listcol1,'###') a inner join       
dbo.splitstring(@listcol2,'###') b on a.id=b.id where table2.listid=@nid
```